# Nested for loop filling an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a nested for loop that fills in values in an array from 1 to 20.

IE) array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

int array[20];

```
for(int i = 0; i<21; i++)
{
    for(int j =1; j<21; j++)
    {
         array[i] = j;
        cout<< array[i];
    }

}
```

Supposedly, The array index should count up with "i", and should be equated to "j" which is also counting up. The array element is printed to the console as it is filled.

I expected 1 -20 to be printed out once, but when I run the code, 1-20 prints out multiple times. Can someone tell me the problem? Thanks!

Comment: for each value of i you execute the inner loop. So you will print 21 times the filling of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Your outer for loop runs 21 times, your inner for loop runs 20 times each of the outer for loop iterations, so you have a total of `21 * 20 = 420` print statements.

You can simply do

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
    cout << array[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your array when you're done, it will also be just a series of 20s. The first loop is saying "do this 20 times" and then the second loop is saying "set and print the value of that array element 20 times." What you need to do is include a check for whether you're assigning the correct j value to the correct array[i] value, and only set the value in that case. Something like:

```
if (j == i + 1) array[i] = j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a nested loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    array[i] = i + 1;
    cout<< array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have two loops when you only need one:

```
for(int i = 0; i<21; i++)
{
  array[i] = i + 1;
  cout<< array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill the array and to print the result you just need two simple for loops

```
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    array[i] = j;
}

for(int j =0; j<20; j++)
{
    cout<< array[i];
}
```

The nested loop that you created above will do exactly what you described.
For each loop of the outer for loop it will execute the full 20 loops of the inner loop.
so in total you will execute it 21 * 20 times.

Also be careful with your index. You want to start with `int i = 0`  to i `< 20` which loops exactly 20 times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are attempting to print a single element in you array, but it isn't necessary to use nested loops here; in fact, a loop isn't required at all:

```
// vector version
std::vector<int> vec(20);
std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);

// array version
int arr[20];
std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 1);
```

If you want to print out the whole array after you've initialized it:

```
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people answered about this question, so I will not repeat them, I'll just mention that you are writing outside the array size.
if you have `int array[20]`, you should loop

> for(int i = 0; i<**20**; i++)
>   the last index is 19

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop 21 times repeats the inner loop

```
for(int i = 0; i<21; i++)
{
    for(int j =1; j<21; j++)
    {
         array[i] = j;
        cout<< array[i];
    }

}
```

The inner loop does the same operation that is assigns elements of the array sequantial numbers. Moreover your code has a bug because due to the outer loop youare trying to access element array[20] that does not exist, because if the array was defined as

```
int arrat[20];
```

then the valid indicies are 0 - 19.

That do not bother about writing correctly required loop or loops you could use standard algorithm `std::iota`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 20;
   int array[N];

   std::iota( std::begin( array ), std::end( array ), 1 );
   std::copy( std::begin( array ), std::end( array ), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
}
```

Or instead of the algorithms you could use the range based for statement. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 20;
   int array[N];
   int i = 1;

   for ( int &x : array )
   {
       x = i++;
       std::cout << x << ' ';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use nested solution, (for example game board coordinates) then this is my solution.

```
// nesting arrays for example game board coordinates                                                                                                                                       

#include <iostream>

  int main(){
  int x = 20;
  int y = 40;

  int array[x][y];

  // initialize array of variable-sized.                                                                                                                                
  for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < y; ++j){
      array[i][j] = 0; // or something like i + j + (i * (y-1)) if you wish                                                                                             
      // and send it to cout                                                                                                                                            
      std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  //notice, that when sent to cout like this, x and y flips on screen, but                                                                                              
  //logics of coordinates is ok                                                                                                                                         

  // and then do something usefull with it                                                                                                                              

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int size = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {    int array[i];
        array[i] = i + 1;
        cout << array[i]<< " ";
   }
```

You could populate your array with 1 for loop, and gauge the size of your array like stated above.